# Ansible read from directory and loop on these items

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to loop over a directory called `environments` where my envs are declared as `yml` files like *description, name, stage*

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── deploy-topics.yml
├── requirements.yml
└── roles
    ├── configuration
    │   ├── environments
    │   │   ├── dev-01.yml
    │   │   └── dev-new.yml
    │   ├── tasks
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   └── topics
    │       └── test_topic.yml
```

I have tried out with `with_fileglob` but need to have conditional check on the stage within the content of the files that are looped over. That means I need to read the file and if the `stage` equal to the attribute in the topics folder I want to run the task. Is there neat solution how I could achieve it?

```
- name: get all environments
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  command: "cat {{ items }}"
  with_fileglob:
    roles/configuration/environments/*.yml
  register: environments
```

Comment: I think you want to use the `group_vars` and `host_vars` directories to achieve this. Please take a look at the Ansible documentation on this here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data